# Microsoft Active Accessibility

Tags: javascript, c++, accessibility

I am working on an 3D Space planning application developed using C++ (DirectX). The UI has been created with user defined types using xml and javascript.There is an id for each UI element in the xml files. How can I set Microsoft Active Accessibility for this application?